# Sub-viewmodels in Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Well met!

I am playing around with Knockoutjs with the goal of having a single ViewModel, which controls multiple sub-viewmodels. This in order to have more control over the views itself and to prevent putting various parts of my view into their own little place. The code below should explain my idea:

**ApplicationViewModel**

```
ApplicationViewModel = function () {
var self = this;

// Context (for laziness' sake, no separate VM)
self.activeProject = ko.observable();

// States
self.projectsLoaded = ko.observable(false);

// State-change events
// Let application know that loading of projects has been called
self.projectsLoaded.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue === true) {
        console.log('Projects have loaded');
    } else {
        console.log('Projects have not loaded');
    }
});
// Let application know that selection of a project has happened
self.activeProject.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue != null) {
        // Notify other viewmodels that a project has been (successfully loaded)
        // Use hook-pattern to hook into this event
    } else {
        // Notify something went wrong- present user with a notification
        // Application stops processes that are project-dependant
    }
});

self.ProjectViewModel = new ProjectViewModel();
};
```

**ProjectViewModel**

```
ProjectViewModel = function () {
var self = this;

self.projects = ko.observableArray();

self.loadProjects = function () {
    // Business logic to retrieve projects, think AJAX
    var placeHolderProjects = [];

    // Find projects somewhere and load them up!

    // If something went wrong, notify parent
    if (placeHolderProjects.length > 0) {
        self.projects(placeHolderProjects);
        $root.projectsLoaded(true);
    } else {
        $root.projectsLoaded(false);
    }
};

self.selectProject = function (projectId) {
    if (!projectId) {
        $.parent.activeProject = null;
        return;
    }

    // Fetch data for project, stuff like membershipId
    var loadProjectResult = magicalLoadFunction(projectId);

    if (loadProjectsResult === true) {
        $root.activeProject(projectId);
    } else {
        $root.activeProject(projectId);
    }

    // Exit
    return;
}

/********** Constructor logic
****************************/
self.loadProjects();
};
```

So basically, what I am looking for, is a way to:
- Control parent/child properties from their respective child/parent *inside* the viewmodels.

I am looking into AngularJS as well, but I'd really like to get this working in KnockoutJS first :) Immediate problem, is that I can't get $root/$parent to work. I bind the ApplicationViewModel in a $(document).ready() handler, unsure if I have to actually bind the sub-viewmodels to the view as well. I have bound ApplicationViewModel to the body element.

Thanks for reading and, possibly for answering/helping me get on my way :)

Comment: Your ProjectViewModel could take a parameter, eg. "parent", and when you instantiate it from ApplicationViewModel you do it with `self.ProjectViewModel = new ProjectViewModel(this)`. But it might be better to have your child view models expose functions or observables that the parent view can use, so the child view model doesn't have to know about its parent. That usually makes the code clearer, but your use case might differ.

Comment: @JanSommer: thanks for the suggestion, I am trying it out. As for exposing functions/observables, that's how I generally do it before this testcase of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by @jansommer proved successful.

I changed the following line (added this as a parameter):

```
self.ProjectViewModel = new ProjectViewModel(this);
```

And that was what was needed.

Thanks!